# Python Object initialization,_init_ method

Tags: python, class, oop

How Can I create class if i have to create object for my class like below.

```
Obj1 = Class()
Obj2 = Class(para1,para2,para3)
```

This is related to a task that i need to complete just started learning Python.

I tried construction overloading but it seems to not work in Python .Can anyone tell me how can i achieve this or it is technically wrong to have both line in one code.

Comment: Is there any other way I have achieve this method

Comment: In Python you are using dynamic function arguments with defaults like `def __init__(para1=None, para2=None, para3=None)` where `None` can be any default value. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions for details!

Comment: Python does not supports method overloading like C++

Answer (score 2):

You can use `*args` or `**kwargs`

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass


obj1 = Class1()
obj2 = Class1(para1,para2,para3)
```

or

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        pass


obj1 = Class1()
obj2 = Class1(para1=para1,para2=para2,para3=para3)
```

Refer this to learn more about [`*args` and `**kwargs`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/)

Answer (score 1):

If you set default values like length = 80, you don't have to set them. But if you set the values, it ll be set as you wish. The following code demonstrates almost what you want.

```
class Rectangle:
   def __init__(self, length = 80, breadth = 60, unit_cost=100):
       self.length = length
       self.breadth = breadth
       self.unit_cost = unit_cost

   def get_perimeter(self):
       return 2 * (self.length + self.breadth)

   def get_area(self):
       return self.length * self.breadth

   def calculate_cost(self):
       area = self.get_area()
       return area * self.unit_cost
# r = Rectangle() <- this returns with default values
# breadth = 120 cm, length = 160 cm, 1 cm^2 = Rs 2000
r = Rectangle(160, 120, 2000)
print("Area of Rectangle: %s cm^2" % (r.get_area()))
print("Cost of rectangular field: Rs. %s " %(r.calculate_cost()))
```